# stopApp() or session$close() dockerized Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

So I have a Shiny app dockerized on Digital Ocean.

I would like to disconnect a user after 30 minutes to keep the app running smoothly (active or inactive user doesnt matter)

So I added this code to close the session using the `shinyjs` package:

```
delay(1000*60*30, suppressWarnings(session$close()))
```

This is correct right?

I wonder if I change `session$close()` to `stopApp()`..this will kick out all user once the first user app is closed correct?

Using ShinyProxy `stopApp()` can be used cause every user has an own docker image spinned up, also correct? Or is it sill advisable to use `session$close()`